# Is it safe to use AWS Cognito on the server-side with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

If AWS Cognito is used with Node.js on the server-side, aren't the passwords, which are sent over, exposed without any form of encryption? AWS Cognito is intended to be used on the client-side, however I could get it work in my Node.js code, but I am wondering if a password is sent to the server, where it is processed now (instead of the client side), is it protected/encrypted in any ways now?

The AWS Cognito methods are called from the POST methods of my Node.js code. 
E.g. the post method triggered by hitting the submit button on the registration page contains the code below. The password that the server sees through req.body.password seems unprotected to me. Is it?

```
userPool.signUp(req.body.username, req.body.password , attributeList, null, function(err, result){
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);           
    return;
  }
  unconfirmedUser = result.user;
  res.redirect('/userVerification');
});
```

Comment: Yes it is. So you should definetly secure your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it is. 
Store your sensitive keys safely and you can run cognito very securely with Node.js.
In fact, AWS generally provide a place to store environment variables in their services consoles. So they even help you out a bit.